Start new job after stopped current job getting ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter exception in Remote chunking in spring batch 5.1.0
I am trying to implement spring batch remote chunking version 5.1.0 using RabbitMQ. The manager sends the chunks to the worker and the worker processes and replies to the manager. but I'm getting  this exception when I stop the current job(A) and start a new job(B) then pause then restart the previous job(A).
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Message contained wrong job instance id [152] should have been [151].
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
at org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter.getNextResult(ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter.java:233)
at org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter.write(ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter.java:100)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:355)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
at org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter$$SpringCGLIB$$0.write(<generated>)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:203)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.scan(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:576)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.lambda$write$4(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:406)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.handleRetryExhausted(RetryTemplate.java:560)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:405)
at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:263)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.BatchRetryTemplate.execute(BatchRetryTemplate.java:216)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.write(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:414)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:227)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:388)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:312)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:255)
at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:369)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:206)
at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:140)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:240)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:229)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:153)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:418)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:132)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:317)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:157)
at java.base/java.lang.VirtualThread.run(VirtualThread.java:309)

Manager Config:
public class ManagerConfiguration {

    public static final String VALIDATION = "VALIDATION";
    public static final String RESTART_VALIDATION = "RESTART_VALIDATION";
    public static final String SPLIT_STEP = "SPLIT";
    public static final String REPORT = "REPORT";
    public static final String DECIDER = "DECIDER";
    public static final String SKIP_SPLIT = "SKIP_SPLIT";
    public static final String SPLIT = "SPLIT";

    private final CustomChunkListener customChunkListener;
    private final CustomJobListener customJobListener;
    private final CustomStepListener customStepListener;
    private final SkipListeners skipListeners;

    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    private final SplitItemReader splitItemReader;
    private final SplitItemProcessor splitItemProcessor;
    private final SplitItemWriter splitItemWriter;

    @Bean
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
        TaskExecutorJobLauncher jobLauncher = new TaskExecutorJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel requests() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow outboundFlow(AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate) {
        return IntegrationFlow
                .from(requests())
                .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(amqpTemplate).routingKey("requests"))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public QueueChannel replies() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow inboundFlow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlow
                .from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, "replies"))
                .channel(replies())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskletStep validationStep(JobRepository repository, PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager) {
        return new StepBuilder(VALIDATION, repository)
                .<BatchDataReader, BatchDataWriter>chunk(1, platformTransactionManager)
                .reader(itemReader(null))
                .writer(itemWriter())
                .faultTolerant()
                .retryLimit(2)
                .retry(Exception.class)
                .skip(Exception.class)
                .skipLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                .listener(skipListeners)
                .listener(customChunkListener)
                .listener(customStepListener)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskletStep splitStep(JobRepository repository, PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager) {
        return new StepBuilder(SPLIT_STEP, repository)
                .<SplitDataReaderDto, SplitDataReaderDto>chunk(1, platformTransactionManager)
                .reader(splitItemReader)
                .processor(splitItemProcessor)
                .writer(splitItemWriter)
                .faultTolerant()
                .retryLimit(2)
                .retry(Exception.class)
                .skip(Exception.class)
                .skipLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                .listener(skipListeners)
                .listener(customChunkListener)
                .listener(customStepListener)
                .build();
    }

  
    @Bean
    public Job remoteChunkingJob(JobRepository jobRepository, Step splitStep, Step validationStep) {
        return new JobBuilder(VALIDATION, jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(splitStep)
                .next(validationStep)
                .listener(customJobListener)
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        return new VirtualThreadTaskExecutor("Thread ->N");
    }

    @Bean
    public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(2000);  // 2 seconds between retries
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);

        SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(2);  // Retry up to 3 times
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

        return retryTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessagingTemplate messagingTemplate() {
        MessagingTemplate template = new MessagingTemplate();
        template.setDefaultChannel(requests());
        template.setReceiveTimeout(20000); //60 secs
        return template;
    }


    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter<BatchDataWriter> itemWriter() {
        ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter<BatchDataWriter> chunkMessageChannelItemWriter = new ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter<>();
        chunkMessageChannelItemWriter.setMessagingOperations(messagingTemplate());
        chunkMessageChannelItemWriter.setReplyChannel(replies());
        chunkMessageChannelItemWriter.setMaxWaitTimeouts(10000);
        chunkMessageChannelItemWriter.setThrottleLimit(5);
        return chunkMessageChannelItemWriter;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public RemoteChunkHandlerFactoryBean<BatchDataWriter> chunkHandler() {
        RemoteChunkHandlerFactoryBean<BatchDataWriter> remoteChunkHandlerFactoryBean = new RemoteChunkHandlerFactoryBean<>();
        remoteChunkHandlerFactoryBean.setChunkWriter(itemWriter());
        remoteChunkHandlerFactoryBean.setStep(validationStep(null, null));
        return remoteChunkHandlerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public JpaPagingItemReader<BatchDataReader> itemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['jobId']}") String jobId) {
        return new JpaPagingItemReaderBuilder<BatchDataReader>().name("itemReader")
                .entityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory)
                .queryString("SELECT f FROM PrimerFiles WHERE f.id=:jobId")
                .parameterValues(Collections.singletonMap("jobId", jobId))
                .pageSize(5)
                .build();
    }

}

Worker Config
public class WorkerConfiguration {

    private final ItemWriter<BatchDataWriter> itemWriter;
    private final ItemProcessor<BatchDataReader, BatchDataWriter> itemProcessor;

    @Bean
    public Queue requestQueue() {
        return new Queue("requests", false);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue repliesQueue() {
        return new Queue("replies", false);
    }

    @Bean
    public TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange("primer-exchange");
    }

    @Bean
    Binding repliesBinding(TopicExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(repliesQueue()).to(exchange).with("replies");
    }

    @Bean
    Binding requestBinding(TopicExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(requestQueue()).to(exchange).with("requests");
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel requests() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel replies() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow messagesIn(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return IntegrationFlow
                .from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, "requests"))
                .channel(requests())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow outgoingReplies(AmqpTemplate template) {
        return IntegrationFlow.from("replies")
                .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(template)
                        .routingKey("replies"))
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        return new VirtualThreadTaskExecutor("Thread N-> :");
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "requests", outputChannel = "replies", sendTimeout = "10000")
    public ChunkProcessorChunkHandler<BatchDataReader> chunkProcessorChunkHandler() {
        ChunkProcessor<BatchDataReader> chunkProcessor = new SimpleChunkProcessor<>(itemProcessor, itemWriter);
        ChunkProcessorChunkHandler<BatchDataReader> chunkProcessorChunkHandler = new ChunkProcessorChunkHandler<>();
        chunkProcessorChunkHandler.setChunkProcessor(chunkProcessor);
        return chunkProcessorChunkHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(5000);  // 2 seconds between retries
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);

        SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(3);  // Retry up to 3 times
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);

        return retryTemplate;
    }
}

Can anybody please help me to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Seems like messages from different jobs are getting crossed in the same channel. Are you running these jobs in the same JVM? I mean starting stopping restarting with a job operator in the same JVM? This really isn't a good idea when going distributed. The issue should not happen though, as each job has its own correlation id when sending message.
